# Notification from the background

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm currently making a TODO app and I save the date that the user has to do a thing. Let's say that he saves the date 28-7-2016 to do something, I make another column `tobenotified` and I take the date minus it by 1 and save it, so the user should be notified the previous day that tomorrow has a thing to do.

But what if the user has closed the app(killed it). What is the proper way to send a notification from the Realm database when the date `tobenotified` is equal with `NSDate()` / the current date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not as simple like that. Realm queries can neither match against a live-updating current date nor send notifications from the background.

You want to look into `UILocalNotification` and set it up with the `tobenotified` date as `fireDate` and schedule it locally. Note that you will require your users consent and have asked them initially by registering for local notification types so that you're permitted by the OS to schedule and present notifications. Also if the user can modify or delete a reminder, then you need to find a way to identify the notification via the the provided identifier and remove or re-schedule it accordingly.

Comment: Ok actually i was thinking about this but i thought if realm had any library to create simple push notifications (of course with the users allowance) Thanks !